# Is it possible to add a new mesh to an existing armature that has already been animated?

Tags: mesh, armature, parent

I have an armature with an existing animation cycle, and am wondering if I can add a new mesh to it. The first pose of the animation is not well-suited to the mesh pose, and even though the "rest pose" is a standard "arms wide" pose, I can't alter it to fit the mesh in that mode. I'm still working out fine details like this in Blender, and learning what works . . . I haven't found many answers from other sources and am hoping someone might know here. I may be overlooking something. Thanks.
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Hello why don't you change the mesh so that it has a T pose as well and align with the armature shape? You could move the arms with the Pose brush in Sculpt mode